# Functions on Euclidean Space; Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Undergraduate student here, taking real analysis.  I'm stuck on a question of proving that if $A$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $F: \mathbb{R}^p \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is continuous then $F(\overline{A})$=$\overline{F(A)}$.

My attempt at a proof is given below.

We need to prove that $f(a) \in \overline{F(A)} \iff f(a) \in f(\overline{A})$.

For $\Rightarrow$: Assume $f(a) \in \overline{F(A)}$.  Then $a \in \overline{A}$.  If $a \in \overline{A}$, then we know that $f(a) \in f(\overline{A})$.

For $\Leftarrow$: Assume $f(a) \in f(\overline{A})$.  So $a \in \overline{A}$. if $a \in \overline{A}$, we know that $a \in \partial{A}$ or $a \in A^{\circ}$.  If $a \in \partial{A}$, then $f(a) \in \overline{f(A)}$, since $\partial{A} \subset \overline{A}$. Similarly, if  $a \in A^{\circ}$ then $f(a) \in \overline{f(A)}$.

I'm sure there are holes in the proof.  Like I said, I'm stuck and I need some help/pointers.

Comment: Why is that if $f(a) \in \overline{F(A)}$ then $a \in \overline{A}$?

Comment: You need to prove that $y \in ...$ **iff** $y \in ...$, not $f(a)$.

Comment: You need to use boundedness somewhere. Take $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ and $A=\mathbb{R}$ to see why. Note that $F(A) \subset F(\overline{A})$, and so $\overline{F(A) } \subset F(\overline{A})$, when $A$ is bounded, since $\overline{A}$ is compact.

Comment: @copper.hat, isn't $y \in \mathbb{R}^q$ the same as $f(a)=y$?

Comment: Only if there is some $a$  in the relevant set so that $f(a) = y$.

Comment: Yes, but you might be better off trying a sequence approach and the fact that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: @copper.hat if $y \in \overline{F(A)}$, then we know that $y \in F(A)$ or $y \in \partial{F(A)}$, right?  So can't we say that if $y \in F(A)$, then $y \in F(\overline{A})$, since $F(A) \subset F(\overline{A})$?  And can't we make a similar statement about the case when $y \in \partial{A}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to get at. You need to use the fact that $A$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill in the details of this argument:

To see that $\overline{F(A)}\subset F(\bar{A})$, note $\bar{A}$ is compact. So $F(\bar{A})$ is a compact, hence closed, subset of $\Bbb R^d$. As $F(\bar{A})$ is a closed set containing $F(A)$, $\overline{F(A)}\subset F(\bar{A})$.

To prove $F(\bar{A})\subset \overline{F(A)}$, take an arbitrary $z\in F(\bar{A})$. Then $z = F(u)$ for some $u\in \bar{A}$. There is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = u$. Then $z = F(u) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} F(a_n) \in \overline{F(A)}$. Hence, $F(\bar{A})\subset \overline{F(A)}$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would happen if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p}$? It seems like you can't assume that there is a sequence $(a_n)$, can you?

Comment: I don't see what you mean @Mr.F, since $A\subset \Bbb R^p$ already. Also, elements of $\bar{A}$ are limits of sequences in $A$, for if $u\in \bar{A}$, then for each $n$, there exists $a_n \in B_{1/n}(u)\cap A$. Thus $\|a_n -u\| < 1/n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$, forcing $a_n \to u$.

Comment: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p}$, then $A$ could potentially be the entire space $\mathbb{R}^{p}$, couldn't it?  If $A$ is unbounded, I'm having trouble seeing how we can say there's a convergent sequence.  Otherwise, I feel like I understand everything else.

Comment: @Mr.F if $A = \Bbb R^p$, then every $a\in \bar{A}$ is the limit of the constant sequence $\{a,a,a,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Now it makes sense.  Thanks so much, you've helped a ton.

Comment: @GeorgeOscarBluth could you please explain why you unchecked my answer?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit the uncheck button.